# Neo4j conditional intersection of optional matchings

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

```
 MATCH (category:Category {id:'123'} ),
                     (stream:Stream {id:'567'} )
 OPTIONAL MATCH path=(stream)-[:CONTAINS]->(categories:Category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(subcats2:Category)<-[:PHOTO_OF]-(photo)
 with stream, subcats2, photo
 OPTIONAL MATCH (stream)<-[:PARTICIPANT_OF]-(users:User)-[:OWNER]->(photo)-[:PHOTO_OF]->(subcats:Category
 return photo
```

I want to have this query like;

if stream `contains` categories do the first optional

if stream (has) `participants` users do the second optional

if has both return the intersection of photos

But in the query above; it is like union query, it returns OK if stream has participants OR users, but fails to take the intersection if it has both categories and users.

NEED SOMETHING LIKE

```
MATCH (category:Category {id:'123'} ),
      (stream:Stream {id:'567'} )
MATCH (stream)-[:CONTAINS]->(categories:Category)
WITH count(categories) as cat_count
IF cat_count > 0
     MATCH path=(stream)-[:CONTAINS]->(categories:Category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(subcats2:Category)<-[:PHOTO_OF]-(photo)
     with stream, subcats2, photo
MATCH (stream)-[:PARTICIPANT_OF]->(users:User)
WITH count(users) as user_count
IF user_count > 0
     MATCH (stream)<-[:PARTICIPANT_OF]-(users:User)-[:OWNER]->  (photo)-[:PHOTO_OF]->(subcats:Category
return photo
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is `subcats` supposed to be `subcats2`?

Comment: they are different subcats, it is not the important part @cybersam

Comment: I was not trying to imply that it was the most important thing :-), but it does affect any potential solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a union where the second part also checks if it is not to be used:

```
MATCH (stream:Stream {id:'567'} )
WHERE size((stream)-[:CONTAINS]->()) > 0
MATCH (category:Category {id:'123'} )
MATCH path=(stream)-[:CONTAINS]->(categories:Category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]-(category)-[:CHILD_OF*0..50]->(subcats2:Category)<-[:PHOTO_OF]-(photo)
RETURN stream, subcats2 as category, photo

UNION 

MATCH (stream:Stream {id:'567'} )
WHERE size((stream)-[:CONTAINS]->()) = 0
MATCH (category:Category {id:'123'} )
MATCH (stream)<-[:PARTICIPANT_OF]-(users:User)-[:OWNER]->(photo)-[:PHOTO_OF]-(category)
return stream, category,photo
```

Comment: In this case it does not return the intersection set of photos if first query returns, second query should use the photo returned from first query

Comment: I need to use the `photo` from first query in the second one